# UIButton not responding to 'touchUpInside' but will respond to 'touchDown' fine

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, human-interface, uicontrolevents

In my program, I have a UIButton declared programmatically as a property of a `UIVIewController`. I have set it up to send actions when the user triggers the `touchUpInside` event, as shown here:

`[restartButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRestart) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`
where `restartButton` is the name of the `UIButton`.

When I enter `UIControlEventTouchDown` in the `forControlEvents` parameter, it works fine. However, `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` simply does not work. Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: Did you by any chance override `touchesMoved` or `touchesEnded`?

Comment: No, but this method is preferable to that if there is a way to make it work.

Comment: You should try to get it working in _normal way_ with `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. I was just asking because that (overriding) could be the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check the `restartButton.bounds`. You may simply have it set to a size of zero causing `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` never to occur. Best way of checking for it is to add borders to layer.

```
[restartButton.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[restartButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
```

Don't forget to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` for above to work

Comment: I just tried that, the size isn't 0. The border fits perfectly around the button. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try TouchUpOutside event?

Comment: This was my problem.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11667958/607730. The parent view had a UITapGestureReconizer on it that was intercepting the TouchUpInside event but allowing the touch down even through.